# Structuring react project with flow type for best type reusability

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, type-safety

I've came into a problem where I have to re-type / re-define repeating types in my *store* / *view* / *components* files i.e. Think a view that takes in some store value and has a function that alters that value and this function is passed down to a component.

There is a lot of type re-usability happening here and I went on to research how to structure projects for this, but didn't find anything useful. What I did find is [$PropertyType](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-propertytype) utility class, that led me to the following approach

```
// @flow
import React, {Component}
import OtherComponent from "./OtherComponent"

export type MyComponentProps = {
  something: string
}

export type MyComponentState = {
  something2: boolean
}

export type MyComponentActions = {
  check: (
    something2: $PropertyType<MyComponentState, 'something2'>,
    something: $PropertyType<MyComponentProps, 'something'>
  ) => string
}

class MyComponent extends Component<MyComponentProps, MyComponentState> {

  state = { something: /* comes from somewhere else i.e store */ false }

  check: $PropertyType<MyComponentActions, 'check'> = (something2, something) => something2 ? "Default" : something

  render() {
    return <OtherComponent foo={this.check} />
  }
}
```

This is a somewhat of useless example, but it shows the pattern I chose, this way `OtherComponent` can import these types i.e. for `check` function and use `$PropertyType` in it when it is specifying its `foo` prop type.

It works, but is extremely verbose, hence I wanted to ask community for alternative suggestions.

My main goal is to be able and re-use these types without the need to re-type them a lot in a clean manner.

Comment: It would be much cleaner with separate types for `something`, `something2` and `check`. Why don't you define it explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a general answer to this problem and I cannot give you a definite answer here. I have been working with flow now extensively for 1,5 years and also together with React for a year now. Here are some tips for working with types.

**1. Use type inference**

Flow is really powerful when it comes to inferring types. Together with the following tips you can avoid making a lot of annotations. Flow will just figure out that things work. You can also make use of the `typeof` annotation to get the type of a value.

**2. Model your domain with types not the interfaces of the components**

This was mentioned in the comments already. Use types to model your domain. E.g. if you work with a component that displays a user, model the user object, not the interface of the component. You can then import the user type in the components that use it.

```
type User = { id: string, name: string };
type ProfilePropType = { user: User };

class Profile extends Component<ProfilePropType> {
  // ...
}
```

**3. Use state management**

Redux for example could help you with the types here. This will give you a structure for your domain types and also reduces how many props are passed around. Another blessing is GraphQL and Apollo Client / Relay.

**4. Generate types programmatically**

We are generating types from our Postgres schema via [postloader](https://github.com/gajus/postloader) in the backend and types for our GraphQL queries in the frontend. Currently we are working on generating types for *react-semantic-ui* from their documentation. After that there are not many types left to write ourselves. There are probably some tools around for your use case.

*One last thing:*

Types are verbose. Sometimes it is good to be explicit. The idea is that types reduce the time you spend searching for bugs by forcing you to be explicit about things. Often it is okay to redefine things. This will also lead to way better errors than using `$PropertyType` because Flow will give you two types that are incompatible instead of cryptic messages.